# How do I use Template Literal for looping functions?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I could find some similar quesitons but I don't think the similar questions answers my question.

I made variables

```
line1 =[]
line2= []
line3 = []
line4 =[]
```

and I made a function drawline()

I would like to do looping like

```
for (let i = 1; i<5; i++){
drawline(`line${i}`)
}
```

However, there was an error message saying 'line' wasn't defined.
I think I understood template literal, but it tells me that I don't understand it fully.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use an array of arrays instead

Comment: Thank you, You meant it's not template literal?

Comment: You can't evaluate variables from strings with template literal. What you have, is a template literal, but you should not use it like that. Use nested arrays instead.

Comment: so it's going to be like, 
        for(let i=0;i<4;i++){
 drawline(line[i])
}
am i right? if not, please correct me.

Comment: Yes, and `line` should be like `const line = [[/* the content of line1 */], [/* the content of line2 */], ... ,  [/* the content of lineN */]]`.

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, one more question. what is /* */?

Comment: ?? It's a JS comment, it's just a placeholder for the content you really have in the array variables in your example.

Comment: @Teemu lol got ya, I haven't look into the shape of comment out. I just unconsciously press command slash. Thanks